# Does import order matter?

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, python-asyncio, mysql-connector-python

I have been running a code that receives data from a server using `websockets`, and stores the received data to a `MySQL` server with `mysql-connector-python`. It has been running successfully so far, but I recently encountered an `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError` for some reason.

After breaking the code into small pieces, I found that the order of importing `asyncio` and `mysql-connector-python` matters, but I'm still not sure why it does. So far, I have known that each module is self-contained, hence the import order would not matter in any cases, but it doesn't seem true.

Please help me understand why this happens, and if possible, share a method to debug this kind of problems.

- Platform: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Python: Python 3.8.10
- mysql-connector-python: 8.0.28
- websockets: 10.1

It runs without an error when I import `asyncio` in advance of `mysql`.

```
import asyncio

from mysql.connector import pooling
import websockets

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        asyncio.run(self.connect())

    async def connect(self):
        async with websockets.connect("wss://localhost:8765") as websocket:
            print("Hello!")

worker = Worker()
```

However, the code that follows results in `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError`.

```
from mysql.connector import pooling
import websockets

import asyncio

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        asyncio.run(self.connect())

    async def connect(self):
        async with websockets.connect("wss://localhost:8765") as websocket:
            print("Hello!")

worker = Worker()
```

Comment: I'm confused; you're connecting using `ws://`; I was under the impression  that you needed to connect using `wss://` in order to use SSL (in other words, I wouldn't expect a certificate error in any circumstance when connecting to a `ws://` socket). Are you certain your `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError` corresponds to the code you've shown in your question?

Comment: In general the import order doesn't matter. The exception is when the import has side effects. The first time a Python module is imported, the module-level code is executed. It's quite possible that `mysql.connector` is doing something when it's imported. I don't have a copy of its source code to look at, but that's usually the first thing I look at in situations like this.

Comment: @larsks Sorry, I missed 's' while replacing a real URI with the localhost. Will edit the question.

Comment: @dirn Thanks for your comment. You commented exactly what I'm suspecting. I have a copy of `mysql.connector`, but I'm not sure what it is doing, even though I looked through the source code.